# $routeProvider behaving oddly (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got this code

```
var site = angular.module('site', ['ngRoute']).
config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {templateUrl: '/NexGaming/pages/home.html', controller: 'mainStaysCtrl'}).
        /*when('/', {templateUrl: '/na/pages/home.html', controller: 'mainStaysCtrl'}).*/           
        when('/in-play', {templateUrl: '/na/pages/in-play.html', controller: 'mainStaysCtrl'}).
        when('/popular', {templateUrl: '/na/pages/popular.html', controller: 'mainStaysCtrl'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/home', tempalteUrl: '/NexGaming/pages/home.html'});
});

site.controller('mainStaysCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
$scope.setRoute = function(route) {
    $location.path(route);
};
});
```

It basically works as it was intended - links with ng-click"setRoute()" calls the tempalte to be displayed in ng-view. All is good.

But for some reason it stops working after few clicks. I mean, for first 3 to 5 clicks it works as it should. And then it stops. Nothing happens. As if setRoute controller would break itself. Do you have any ideas?

**EDIT**

As it appers, this bug disables ALL THE LINKS on the site. Even those hardcoded.

Comment: `tempalteUrl` is misspelled in your last route.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. It didn't help though.

Comment: I'll bet there's an error message in your Javascript console when it stops working.  What does it say?

Comment: There's none. That's the point. After further inspections I noticed it's like this: You can't click a link twice. It works only at the first try.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake. Link looked like this

```
<a href="" class="ahref"><div class="bullet-link" ng-click="setRoute('/popular')">Popular Events</div></a>
```

And it should look like this

```
<a href="#/popular" class="ahref"><div class="bullet-link" ng-click="setRoute('/popular')">Popular Events</div></a>
```